# Почему не работает этот SQL запрос?

Tags: sql

Почему это работает:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID=1
```

А это - нет:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE key='value'
```

Колонки: ID, key, value

Comment: а нечего поля ключевыми словами называть а потом задаваться подобными вопросами

Comment: Опишите подробнее задачу. В данный момент я лишь вижу, что вы пытаетесь имя одной колонки сравнить с именем другой.

Comment: Покажите, что у вас в таблице

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/ewOJuEx.png

Comment: Как выбрать значнеия, где колонка key равна значению value.

Comment: Изучите список служебных и зарезервированных слов в своей СУБД. Переименуйте поля.

Comment: Так если это поле, то может надо без кавычек писать: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE key=value` Или, если на что-то будет ругаться, то надо там какие-то специальные кавычки, я не очень в курсе про `SQL`. Где-то скобки вроде работают `[value]`, где-то ещё что-то, от БД зависит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Table` является зарезервированным словом MySQL. Чтобы ваш запрос выполнился, необходимо везде `table` взять в обратные кавычки `` `table` ``.

Посмотрите в тренажёре:
https://www.mycompiler.io/view/Ak1jn0rTG9r (нажмите RUN для запуска компилятора).

Вообще, лучше избегать в именовании столбцов таблиц и самих таблиц зарезервированных слов, их довольно много. Смотрите здесь: http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Reserved_words.html

И уберите кавычки у `'value'`, если вы ищете только те строки, в которых значения `key` и `value` совпадают.

Ваш запрос должен выглядеть так:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE key = value;
```

Или даже так:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `key` = `value`;
```

Если это не сработает, попробуйте заменить имя таблицы на `mytable`, например.